# Binomial Identity problem

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I've been working on this binomial identity problem for hours but I seriously have no clue how to deal with this. Here's the problem:

Evaluate the sum
$$1 + 2C(n,1) + \cdots (k + 1)C(n,k) + \cdots + (n + 1)C(n, n)$$
by breaking this sum into two sums, each of which is an identity in this
section.

(I don't even understand what the question actually means - "by breaking this sum into two sums?")

Please please please someone help me. this is killing me inside :(

Comment: Hint: the given sum is $\sum_{j = 0}^n j \binom{n}{j}$. Can you rewrite the summand as something you know?

Comment: Hint: $\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$

Comment: Appreciate your help guys. But still no clue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^n (k+1)\binom{n}{k}&=\sum_{k=1}^nk\binom{n}{k}+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n n\binom{n-1}{k-1}+(1+1)^n\tag{1}\\
&=n\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}+2^n\\
&=n\sum_{u=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{u}
+2^n\\
&=n2^{n-1}+2^n
\end{align}
$$
where in (1) we used the identities
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}=2^n
$$
a consequence of the binomial theorem and
$$
k\binom{n}{k}=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}\quad(n\geq k\geq1)
$$

Comment: Thank you. One question: on the first line, where did k=1 come from? why not k=0?

Comment: You could put $k=0$ but remember that the term corresponding to $k=0$ would vanish anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{j=0}^n \binom njx^j\equiv(1+x)^n$$

What happens if you differentiate both sides of the above identity wrt $x$ and set $x=1$ ?

---

Edit:

It seems your sum is $\sum\limits_{k=0}^n(k+1)\binom nk=2^n+\sum_{k=0}^nk\binom nk$ where you can evaluate the latter sum using the above hint.

---

Here's one algebraic approach similar to the one Gauss used to calculate the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers.

Let $S:=\sum\limits_{j=0}^n j\binom nj$. Then, since $\binom nj=\binom n{n-j}$, we have,

$$2S=\sum_{j=0}^nj\binom nj+\sum_{j=0}^n(n-j)\binom nj=n\sum_{j=0}^n\binom nj=n2^n\implies S=n2^{n-1}$$

Comment: Why did you use differentiation?? I'm sorry I think I'm just completely lost in this topic :(

Comment: @SubinPark: Because it makes the problem easier noting that the derivative of $\binom njx^j$ wrt $x$ is $j\binom njx^{j-1}$; now set $x=1$ to get your desired sum.

Comment: @SubinPark: I have added an algebraic way to do it.